# Symbolic Comparison

Tags: algorithm, math, comparison, logic, discrete-mathematics

Please forgive me if this is a basic problem or if there is already abundant solutions, but I don't know how to articulate this this problem concisely and I could not find any results for this.  I have been thinking about this problem for a long time and I cannot seem to find a solution.

What I want to do is compare symbolic statements through strings.  For example, in mathematics,

```
4x = 4x is true.
```

But what about

```
(12/3)x = 4x
(5-1)x = (4/1)x 
((5-1)/1)x = (4/1)x
so on . . .
```

In proofs,

```
1 = sin(x)^2 + cos(x)^2
tan(x) = sin(x)/cos(x)
sin(2x) = 2*sin(x)*cos(x)
and so on . . .
```

In logic,

```
~~p <-> p
~(p * q) <-> (~p v ~q)
~(p v q) <-> (~p * ~q)
(p v q) <-> (q v p)
(p * q) <-> (q * p)
and so on . . .
```

Keep in mind that these inputs are strings.  The problem I'm running into is that there is theoretically an infinite amount of cases where both sides can be equal.

Of course the first problem is how to parse numerical values versus symbolic values and enumerate them.  I am OK on this end.

I don't even know where to begin so any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: It boils down to simplification algorithms for expression trees. For some reason a lot of people use `LISP` for this task, and I do not know why.

Comment: @ja72: I think people use LISP because of its symbolic manipulation facilities, but it may also be historical.  In fact, many of the early computer algebra systems were written in LISP, and one of the comments to my answer referenced a book that used a dialect of LISP (Scheme) for its system.

Comment: i really don't understand why this is closed as **not constructive**. is it because there is no code involved? because relevant information *was* introduced by reputable sources and while I didn't get a code example, at least I got some serious theoretical solutions. even the solution themselves are very daunting to comprehend and impliment.  there was only one answerer and another useful commenter so the only person who answered pointed me to the right direction and got the points.  there is no debate, argument, or polling.  i dont get why it's being closed at all.

Comment: @rtbLong: This isn't the first time I was puzzled by a question getting closed.  I just skimmed the FAQ and did not find any reason this question should have been closed.  If it was a duplicate, someone would have said so and pointed to a link.

Comment: You can also use Prolog. For the abstract technique see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would get a symbolic algebra package. They can do things like derivations, simplifications and comparisons with reductions.  Many are also programmable.  There are some good free ones out there.

There's a list here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems

If you are looking for a way of doing this in your code, perhaps you could find a symbolic algebra library for the language of your choice.

Comment: Excellent answer. If you're looking for more background, the Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs videos on Symbolic Differentiation (and computer algebra) are an excellent starting place for research. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/3b-symbolic-differentiation-quotation/

Comment: @AndrewWalker: Thank you. And a huge kudos for SICP.  This is a superb book, well worth reading for its own sake.  It may qualify as the finest CS book I ever read.